Rotation of a function on the unit sphere
Let $u$ be a smooth function on the sphere such that $|\nabla u(0,0,1)|=|\nabla u(0,0,-1)|\neq 0$. Let $\hat{u}(x)=u(-x)$ be the reflection of $u$ with respect to the origin. I wonder if there is a rotation (about $z$-axis ) $R_\theta$ such that the gradient of the function
$$ \hat{u}(R_\theta(x))-u(x)$$
vanishes on $(0,0,\pm1)$. Intuitively if $\theta$ is the angle between $\nabla u(0,0,1)$ and $\nabla u(0,0,-1)$, then a rotation by $\theta$ or $-\theta$ seems to work, but I have a hard time making the argument rigorous.

I do not know what $\tilde u$ means. Do you mean $\hat u$? What does the chain rule tell you about the gradient of $\hat u$? The gradient of $\hat u(R_\theta(x))$?

By $\theta$, do you mean the azimuthal or polar angle ?

ALso did you make a mistake and mean to simply define $\tilde{u}(x):=u(Rx)$?

@TedShifrin Yes, I meant $\hat{u}$ and not $\tilde{u}$.

@K.defaoite Yes, I revised the question.

@TedShifrin I thought I figured this out yesterday, but I was wrong. Do you think my intuition is correct?

Let $v(x)=u(-R_\theta x)$. The chain rule tells us that
$$Dv(x) = -Du(-R_\theta x)R_\theta, \quad\text{and so}\quad \nabla v(x) = -R_\theta^\top\nabla u(-R_\theta x).$$
Note that $-R_\theta^\top = -R_{-\theta}$. Letting $P=(0,0,1)$ be the north pole, then we have
$$\nabla v(P) = -R_{-\theta}\nabla u(-P).$$
Thus, since you are asking to have
$\nabla v(P)= \nabla u(P)$ and $\nabla v(-P)= \nabla u(-P)$, this leads us to
$$\nabla u(-P) = -R_{\theta}\nabla u(P) \quad\text{and}\quad \nabla u(P) = -R_{\theta}\nabla u(-P).$$
That is $R_{\theta}$ has to interchange $\nabla u(P)$ and $-\nabla u(-P)$.
One possibility is for $\nabla u(P) = -\nabla u(-P)$ to be vertical. The general case seems to be that $\nabla u(P)=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ and $-\nabla u(-P)=(-\alpha,-\beta,\gamma)$ with $\theta=\pi$. Other ideas?
